# Adding features to featureCollection does not update the map

Tags: geotools, linestring, map-drawing, feature-collection, addlayer

I am trying to draw lines on the map using GeoTools, and my goal here is to prevent reloading the window when I draw lines on the map every time.

I created a layer based on a featureCollection and added features to that layer each time when I draw a line on the map. The problem is when I draw a line, the line layer is not updating. But when I click the button with two arrows on it above the window, the lines are coming. Please help me on how can I make the line layer update without clicking this button?

In my code, you can draw lines by clicking 2 times in the map frame.

```
package org.geotools.tutorial.feature;

        import java.awt.*;
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.*;
        import java.util.List;

        import org.geotools.data.FileDataStore;
        import org.geotools.data.FileDataStoreFinder;
        import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
        import org.geotools.feature.DefaultFeatureCollection;
        import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureBuilder;
        import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder;
        import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder;
        import org.geotools.map.*;
        import org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS;
        import org.geotools.styling.SLD;
        import org.geotools.styling.Style;
        import org.geotools.swing.JMapFrame;
        import org.geotools.swing.data.JFileDataStoreChooser;
        import org.geotools.swing.event.MapMouseEvent;
        import org.geotools.swing.tool.CursorTool;
        import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
        import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
        import org.locationtech.jts.geom.LineString;
        import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
        import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
        import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
        import org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException;
        import org.opengis.referencing.operation.TransformException;

public abstract class DrawLine {
    static GeometryFactory gf = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // display a data store file chooser dialog for shapefiles
        File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("shp", null);
        if (file == null) {
            return;
        }

        FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();

        // Create a map content and add our shapefile to it
        MapContent map = new MapContent();
        map.setTitle("Geotool application");

        Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
        Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
        map.addLayer(layer);

        JMapFrame mapFrame = new JMapFrame(map);
        mapFrame.enableToolBar(true);
        mapFrame.enableStatusBar(true);
        mapFrame.setSize(1600, 1000);
        mapFrame.setVisible(true);

        List<MapMouseEvent> points = new ArrayList<MapMouseEvent>();

        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        builder.setName("TwoDistancesType");
        builder.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
        builder.add("line", LineString.class);

        final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = builder.buildFeatureType();

        DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection("internal",TYPE);
        SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);

        Style lineStyle = SLD.createLineStyle(Color.red, 2.0f);
        Layer lineLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, lineStyle);
        map.addLayer(lineLayer);

        mapFrame.getMapPane()
                .setCursorTool(
                        new CursorTool() {

                            @Override
                            public void onMouseClicked(MapMouseEvent ev) {
                                try {
                                    if (points.size() == 0) {
                                        points.add(ev);
                                    } else {
                                        Point start = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(points.get(0).getWorldPos().x, points.get(0).getWorldPos().y));
                                        Point end = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(ev.getWorldPos().x, ev.getWorldPos().y));

                                        DrawLine.displayShapefile(  featureCollection, featureBuilder,  start, end);
                                        System.out.println(map.layers());
                                        points.clear();
                                    }
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (FactoryException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (TransformException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        }
                );
    }

    public static void displayShapefile( DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection ,  SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder, Point start, Point end) throws IOException, FactoryException, TransformException {

        Coordinate[] coordinates = {start.getCoordinate(), end.getCoordinate() };
        LineString line = gf.createLineString(coordinates);

        featureBuilder.reset();

        featureBuilder.add(line);

        SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);

        featureCollection.add(feature);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct connection between a `FeatureCollection` and the `MapPane` so until the map receives a request to redraw nothing will happen.

So when you add a new feature you will need to notify the `MapPane` that it needs to rerender. To help you do this there is a `MapLayerEvent.DATA_CHANGED` event which is propagated via the `Layer.fireMapLayerListenerLayerChanged()` method.

Comment: Thank you a lot, after adding a line to the featureCollection, I called getMapPane().reset(); and the line directly show in the map.